# Self-Service Payments for Contribution (Tuition)

Tags: civicontribute, webform-civicrm

CiviCRM 4.7.x and Drupal 7

Requirement:

- Staff creates "Pending" or "Partially Paid" contribution in CiviCRM
  backend.
- User can log on to a page, and make payments against that Contribution until it is paid in full.

Is there any way to do this with CiviCRM or Webform CiviCRM? Would 'Pledges' work?

Alternatively - could we create a Webform-CiviCRM that creates the contribution, and lets someone come back and apply payments to it, displaying the remaining balance? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can certainly achieve this

1. Create a Contribution Page by enabling Other amount and payment processor.
2. Navigate to Administer >> CiviContribute >> CiviContribute Component Settings and select contribution page create at #1 for **Default invoice payment page**
3. Create a contribution for a contact with **pending** status.
4. On User Dashboard of contact (/civicrm/user?cid=[contact_id]) under contribution section you will see pay now button against the pending contribution. When clicked on pay now it will redirect to online contribution page where one can pay pending contribution online using credit card.
   [image]
5. You can also generate the link to pay pending contribution online `http://domainname.com/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=[contribution_page_id]&ccid=[contribution_id]`

where contribution_page_id(id) is contribution page id created at #1 and contribution_id(ccid) is contribution id created at #3.

Comment: It seems to work but I just see the full contribution amount on step 5, not an option for "Other Amount"

Comment: Yes, the online form allows to pay total outstanding amount. Partial Payment through online is not yet supported in CiviCRM. Through backoffice form you can record payment for a pending contribution until its fully paid.

Comment: As a work around I suppose I could create a few "Pending" contributions as "Installments"?

Comment: Yup, that would work :) or create pledges and have user to do pledge payment online.

Comment: Let us know if you willing to pay to develop an extension that will record partial payment online.

Comment: What's your email? I'd love to summarize the features I need and get an estimate. Just quickly, what would it take an extension that does your Step 1-5 but allows the user to enter a custom amount, and have that applied to a "Pending" contribution as additional payments? zkrebs@gmail.com

Comment: Did anything more come of this discussion Pradeep?

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this you would need to write a custom extension for partial payment, this video might help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sxu2vdOrYO8&index=6&list=PLjSU7YfE0E01HW7JPVAI80XDI0sgOSPDs

Github repo: https://github.com/backoffice/BOT-Partial-Payment-Extension

Comment: It seems like the front end extension is missing, I wonder if BOT sells it